# What does it mean to solve a system of linear equations simultaneously?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

A system of linear equations is a finite collection of linear equations that is to be solved simultaneously. 
Does the phrase 'solving the system simultaneously' above mean you deal with the equations all together at once?

Comment: No, it means that a solution must (simultaneously) satisfy all of the equations. It's an idiom.

Comment: @quasi: it's quasi the same.

Comment: @quasi I think a solution is what satisfies all of the equations as Yves Daoust points out. Thank you both for the comments. It is helpful to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have the set of equations
$$
\cases{x + y = 3\\x - y = 1}
$$
then I can solve only the first equation, and I get solutions like $x = 5, y = -2$ or $x = 1003, y = -1000$. There are infinitely many solutions. I can also solve just the second equation and get solutions like $x = -5, y = -6$ or $x = 1000, y = 999$. Here, too, there are infinitely many solutions.

However, one could also try to find some value for $x$ and some value for $y$ which is a solution to the first equation, and *at the same time* (or "simultaneously", if you like) is a solution to the second equation. That is what that word means in this context, and most problems of this kind have exactly one such simultaneous solution.

Answer (score 0):

It means you're looking for a value for each of the unknowns such that *all* of the equations become true.

The term doesn't imply anything about *how* you find that combination -- though generally you would indeed work on all equations together.

Answer (score 0):

This definition is misleading.

IMO, it would be better to say: "A system of linear equations is a finite collection of linear equations *that hold* simultaneously", meaning that any solution must satisfy all the equations.

Then it is trivial that you need to handle them simultaneously while solving.

Comment: I get your point. Thanks for the upgrade in the definition.